# How to create a random list in haskell

Tags: list, haskell, random, list-comprehension

I'm new to haskell and came across this problem: as the title says, I'm trying to create a list of a given length with random numbers, ranging between some x and y. So for example, if x=0 and y=10, the list would be something like: [0,4,3,8,0,2]. I'd prefer to do it with list comprehension and without any IO's. I've seen some posts about similar topics, but none have been helpful to me so far.

Comment: Because what you want is not possible.  Values are deterministic.  No io means no random.

Comment: While @ThomasM.DuBuisson is correct, you can still create psuedo-random lists, that appear random, however you will get the same random list for any given seed.

Answer (score 3):

Using `System.Random` in the `random` package, this is exactly the function `randomRs`:

```
randomRs :: (Random a, RandomGen g) => (a, a) -> g -> [a]
```

It takes a range of values and a generator and returns a lazy list of random values in that range. You can make a generator from a fixed seed using `mkStdGen`:

```
mkStdGen :: Int -> StdGen
```

For example, here’s a seed that (on my machine, with my particular version of `random`) coincidentally produces the example values you gave:

```
> take 6 $ randomRs (0, 10) $ mkStdGen 15915
[0,4,3,8,0,2]
```

If you want the program to produce different random values on each invocation, you *must* use IO to seed the random number generator with the current time. For that you can use `newStdGen` instead:

```
newStdGen :: IO StdGen
```

A complete example:

```
import System.Random (newStdGen, randomRs)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  gen <- newStdGen
  print $ randomList 6 0 10 gen

randomList
  :: (Random a, RandomGen g)
  => Int -> a -> a -> g -> [a]
randomList len lo hi gen = take len $ randomRs (lo, hi) gen
```

Answer (score 1):

The excellent answer by Jon Purdy solves the problem using library function `randomRs`. This works fine.

However, there is the drawback that the **final state** of the random number generator is lost. In the general case, you may have other needs for random numbers, so you need that final state, to use it as the initial state for these *other needs*.

The loss of the final state is linked to the fact that `randomRs` provides an *unlimited* supply of random numbers, so there is no proper final state. But the text of your question mentions “a list of a given length”. So there is no need to use `randomRs`. Instead, you can use function [getRandomR](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.5.1.2/docs/Control-Monad-Random-Class.html#v:getRandomR), which returns a single random number, as the basic building block.

The most general way to do this is to use the [MonadRandom](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom) class with the [runRand](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.5.1.2/docs/Control-Monad-Random-Lazy.html#v:runRand) evaluation function. That gives this sort of source code:

```
import  System.Random
import  System.Random.TF -- Threefish algorithm
import  Control.Monad.Random


-- monadic action to get *count* random numbers between xmin and xmax
someRandomNumbers :: MonadRandom mr => Int -> Int -> Int -> mr [Int]
someRandomNumbers xmin xmax count =
    sequence (replicate count (getRandomR (xmin, xmax)))


main = do
    let count    = 6
        seed     = 377708  -- adjusted to get exactly [0,4,3,8,0,2]  :-)
        randGen0 = mkTFGen seed
        action   = someRandomNumbers 0 10 count

        (xs, randGen1) = runRand action randGen0  -- get final state too
    putStrLn $ "random xs = " ++ (show xs)
```

### Program output:

```
random xs = [0,4,3,8,0,2]
```

**Note 1:** instead of the standard generator, I used the [Threefish random number generator](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tf-random-0.5/docs/System-Random-TF.html), because it is known to have [better statistical properties](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/b82b/c39da0ed8bbe79fa769a2f952ca916fd5900.pdf).

**Note 2:** IO is not involved at all, except when finally printing the results.